# Create a dropdown from multiple tinyint(1) fields in CakePHP

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Currently I'm letting my user choose how they want their event to repeat:  daily, monthly, weekly, or yearly.

I have these as tinyint(1) fields in my database.  So - they're on the page as checkboxes, and I'm using javascript to catch when a user clicks one, and uncheck the rest.  No big deal, and is working just fine.

**TLDR:** 
I would love to be able to have them in a dropdown instead.  Is there a way to convert multiple tinyint(1) fields into a single dropdown?  Or will I just need to do it manually (HTML form field not related to a database field), then convert the data when it comes into the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a "repeating" table for the event repeating period.  The table would have an id and a name field.  Then, in your event field, create a repeating_id field.  You can now create a model to your repeating table and use standard CakePHP conventions to populate the form by passing the results of a "list" operation on the table into your view.

The more I use CakePHP, the more I find approaching solutions this way much easier to create and maintain.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution is the first one I overlook. :(  Thanks!  I'm going to wait for an explanation on the above ones before I decide for sure on the "best" answer, but I'm implemented this one, and it works as expected - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```
$this->set('fields',Set::extract('/COLUMNS/Field', $this->Model->query("DESCRIBE {$this->Model->useTable}")));
```

In your view:

```
$this->Form->input('yourdropdown', array('options' => $fields));
```

Comment: This looks interesting, but I don't completely follow - can you offer a bit of explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a single ENUM field? `repeats enum('daily', 'monthly', 'weekly', 'yearly', 'none')` or somesuch would do the trick.

Comment: This seems awesome - I've never used an ENUM field before.  Any thoughts on the best way to incorporate into Cake?

Comment: I've never used cake, but shouldn't be too hard to create a dropdown with values that match the names you've put into the enum field.